# Is it possible to put downloaded Minecraft mods from the Internet in the play market

Tags: google-play

I want to make a simple play store app for I want to make a simple application on google play store for children under 12 years old, where you can go and download Mods for minecraft pocket edition, but I don’t know if I can add the mods that I downloaded from the Internet there, like I download the mod from the Internet, and create a button in the application when I click on which they will be able to download this mod, and I'm wondering if it's legal, won't it violate copyrights, and is it possible to do so?

I looked at similar applications, they are very crookedly written, in part they even look like On the kiwi python framework, since when the screen was rotated everything blurred, the buttons were set flat, the text is not visible, everything is exactly like on kiwi, and you can download mods from them, and I’m wondering if I can do the same and make money on these applications thanks to advertising? То

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read tour to see what kinds of questions to ask here.  Play store rules and legal questions probably belong somewhere else - https://stackoverflow.com/tour  .  Your technical question about  the steps to have a different app (yours) install a mod to pocket Minecraft might be OK if was written as a narrow, specific question after you do your own research, see how to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask